# Hot to use custom Request class instead NovaRequest (FormRequest) for creating resuorce in Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I make:
`php artisan make:request DiscoverRequest`

I want use `DiscoverRequest` instead default `NovaRequest` for create new entity for specific resource.

In Laravel Nova exist unified `ResourceStoreController` for all resources.

`public function handle(CreateResourceRequest $request)`

`Route::post('/{resource}', 'ResourceStoreController@handle');`

I want to override `Request` only for one resource.

How this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate what you mean by "override Request for only one resource"?

Normally you can just type hint the new Request in the method like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreItineraryRequest;

class ResourceStoreController extends Controller
{
    public function handle(DiscoverRequest $request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep I understand what the documentation is saying, but can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This does not work like that for Laravel Nova. There, all requests use controllers from the vendor directory, it is not clear how to redefine the request in them.